# Code block display within an ordered list?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

I was attempting to edit a post earlier, but couldn't get a code block to display within an ordered list.

I've not found any reference to this directly and despite indenting and trying a few workarounds (` etc), I couldn't get it to work as a code block. Is it possible using SO markdown?:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just an example to show it:

The way to do it :

- is to add *moar* spaces

  ```
  This is code (bunch of spaces [8])
  ```

  this is not code (4 spaces)

This caused because when the text is in a list, the parser takes a 4 spaces indentation for a normal (list) indentation. So you have to put another 4 spaces in order for it to recognize the code block.

Comment: God damn spaces. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: +1 I love the scale of the arrows - Nearly as big as my missing 8 spaces!

Comment: Where are the free-hands drawn stuff? These arrows are way to beautiful to be on the meta!

Comment: @HugoDozois I have a *very* steady hand.